# Adding element <a> before every <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code created by a javascript file, which is not understandable because it was created using GWT(Google Web Toolkit).

```
<img style="z-index: 6; width: 116px; position: absolute; left: 84px; top: 174px;" src="spiral/sample9.jpg">  
<img style="z-index: 12; width: 197px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 161px;" src="spiral/sample1.jpg">
<img style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 659px; top: 213px; width: 85px; opacity: 0.04; display: none;" src="spiral/sample17.jpg">  
<img style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 644px; top: 208px; width: 85px; opacity: 0.08; display: none;" src="spiral/sample18.jpg">
```

Now I need to add the tag `<a>` before every image, using as `src`, part of the `src` of the image. For example: "`href="../tmp.php?title=sample9.mp4`"

Any clue how can I do this?

The output I want to create is something like this:

```
<a href="../tmp.php?title=sample9.mp4"><img style="z-index: 6; width: 116px; position: absolute; left: 84px; top: 174px;" src="spiral/sample9.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: ... What do you think `querySelector` does?

Comment: It returns the element I've specified, I think...

Comment: Element, **singular**.  Also, `document.querySelector("img.src")` doesn't make sense, unless you write `class="src"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and to build the right href you can use a regular expression :

```
$('img').wrap(function(){
    return $('<a>').attr(
        'href',
        '../tmp.php?title=' + this.src.match(/\/(.*?)\.jpg$/)[1] + '.mp4'
    )
});
```

Comment: jquery is no longer a tag on this question. Which is a shame because you're actually doing it right (using `this.src` instead of the abomination that is `$(this).attr('src')`)

Comment: Wait, now it's back. Wish he'd make up his mind... Have a +1 anyway - you're the first person to earn one from me with a jQuery answer :p

Comment: jQuery is again a tag of this post. However the `<a>` tags are not created!

Comment: @zppinto [look at the console to see the resulting HTML](http://jsbin.com/isupom/1/edit).

Comment: @zppinto Why a delay ? That sounds wrong. If you're obtaining the HTML through some kind of AJAX query, then you should use a callback, not a delay.

Comment: Hi have to use a `setTimeout` because, like I said in the topic, the HTML code is created by a JS file which is not understandable, and so I have to guarantee that code is all executed, before execute your function...

Answer (score 6):

With jQuery, you can use [**`wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to do this:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap($('<a/>', {href: this.src}));
});
```

Comment: Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: You can pass a function to `wrap()`.

Comment: @Kolink post was tagged jQuery; I don't think this one counts for the meme.

Comment: @Mathletics Considering the level of JS used by OP, I don't think jQuery should be a tool they should be allowed to have their hands on. Especially since they don't even use it in the question.

Comment: I preferred a code without jQuery... It's true I've had the jQuery tag, but that way I think I can't get it to work!

Comment: I posted this answer **only** because of the jQuery tag. You've effectively **invalidated** my answer by removing the jQuery tag now. :-|

Comment: @Kolink you make a compelling point, and I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: -_- jQuery is back! However, I can get it to work. I have the code in the same html file as the images, and the `<a>` is not created :-/

Comment: @zppinto Make up your mind. You're not being very useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Quite apart from your obvious lack of understanding of the `querySelector` function, you also expect `</img>` to work (it doesn't, it's a void element)...

Here's how you should go about it, with comments to explain:

```
var imgs, l, i, img, par, a; // prepare some variables
imgs = document.getElementByTagName('img');
                             // get all images on the page
l = imgs.length;             // save the number of images (for performance reasons)
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {        // loop through all images
    img = imgs[i];           // for easire access
    par = img.parentNode;    // get the parent of the current image
    a = document.createElement('a');
                             // create a new link
    a.href = "../tmp.php?title="+img.src.match(/([^\/.]+\.\w+$/)[1]+".mp4";
                             // extract the right part from the image source
                             // and put it into the link's href
    par.insertBefore(a,img); // insert the link before the image
    a.appendChild(img);      // move the image so that it is inside the link
}
```